# Virtual Private Hosting DNS configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I did a great deal of reading here before posting this because I didn't want to post a duplicate - but I'm on a bit of a deadline and getting frustrated, so here goes...

> I very, very, very sincerely apologize if this is long winded or hard
>   to read. Please - please just ask for any information or clarification
>   and I will give it as quickly as I possibly can. This has become very
>   frustrating to me and this is the last place I know to turn.

I have no experience with setting up DNS, no experience with nameservers, and no peers to go to for help. So this is kind of my last ditch effort.

The task of setting up a private server has, through circumstances beyond my control, fallen into my lap.

I own a domain (hereafter referred to as **yyy.com)** and have always used shared hosting - I buy a package and just point it to the domain nameservers they give me. It's always been simple.

> yyy.com is registered with *network solutions*

Now I have purchased a Virtual Private Hosting package from GoDaddy.com - and it comes with Plesk 11.

I have no earthly idea how to begin to get the right nameserver for **yyy.com**. I have gone through the instructions and have wound up exceedingly frustrated.

I have 2 IP addresses from GoDaddy for the server. This is what I have so far, and I cannot tell if it is working (Since propogation takes so long, it is extremely hard to test for me)

```
IP 1 : XX.XX.XX.XX 
IP 2 : YY.YY.YY.YY
```

*(obviously hidden for privacy)*

Now after going through the documentation setup and waiting a few days, this is the setup I have - and so far it does not appear to be working.

```
Host                    Record type     Value
XX.XX.XX.XX / 24    PTR             yyy.com.
yyy.com.            NS              ns1.yyy.com.
yyy.com.            A               XX.XX.XX.XX
yyy.com.            MX (10)             mail.yyy.com.
ftp.yyy.com.            CNAME               yyy.com.
ipv4.yyy.com.           A               XX.XX.XX.XX
mail.yyy.com.           A               XX.XX.XX.XX
mssql.yyy.com.          A               XX.XX.XX.XX
ns1.yyy.com.            A               XX.XX.XX.XX
ns2.yyy.com.            A               YY.YY.YY.YY
webmail.yyy.com.    A               XX.XX.XX.XX
www.yyy.com.            CNAME               yyy.com.
```

**yyy.com** is pointing to both *ns1.yyy.com* and *ns2.yyy.com*

Can anyone give me some assistance here? This is a learning experience for me and days of documentation have left me very confused.

Comment: You *must* understand DNS if you're going to have anything to do with hosting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the link you're missing is setting the authoritative name server in GoDaddy's DCC control panel. I'm assuming you registered the domain through GoDaddy. It seems like you're trying to host the DNS records on your VPS -- I'm assuming the DNS zone you pasted is entered in the VPS's Plesk control panel. In your situation, I recommend hosting your DNS elsewhere, for example Amazon's Route53. (There's a charge, but it's quite reasonable.) Whatever you choose, it's important to have at least 2 individual, separate name servers, one being the master and the other(s) being the slave(s). This is automatic with services like Route53.

In any event, you need to specify the domain's name servers in GoDaddy. (https://dcc.godaddy.com/ > click domain > click "set name servers") Doing so will update the root name servers. The zone file should also list the name servers, but without records at the root name servers, this does nothing.

An alternative approach would be to set the name servers to Godaddy's (Click "set nameservers" and choose "I have a hosting account with these domains."

Comment: My domain is on Network Solutions.

Comment: I went to that site and I used the "off site" option - and it gave me the nameservers `mns01.domaincontrol.com` and `mns02.domaincontrol.com` - so I can just plug these in and it should resolve to my virtual dedicated server?

Comment: Man, this is all so confusing. e.e; I added it using the Off-Site option, but all of the records are empty. Is that normal?

Comment: Also, is there any possible way to test that this is working without waiting 48 hours between changes? I'm more confused than ever before.

Comment: I've updated the question to specify that the domain is registered with a different company.

Comment: Alright, I've set up an account with Route53 as per your suggestion and I've pointed it to the Nameservers they gave me - what should I do from there? What values do I want in my PLESK control panel to make sure the site functions?

Comment: When you create a "Hosted Zone" in Route53, it exists on several name servers that are run by Amazon. The [name servers for your domain are listed in Amazon's control panel](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/GetInfoAboutHostedZone.html). You need to [enter these name servers in the Network Solutions control panel](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/move-dns-to-a-new-server/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have managed to get it working using Route53. It was a convoluted process, but I will credit you for the answer and post my findings below. I have some other questions, but I will post them in a different thread.

Comment: Posted my followup question here : http://serverfault.com/questions/451996/setting-up-dns-on-windows-when-using-amazon-route53

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again to **xofer** for the help. Amazon Route53 really did the trick. I have learned so much just by following his instructions. I have posted a followup question [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/451996/setting-up-dns-on-windows-when-using-amazon-route53) but I wanted to outline what I actually did to solve it for anyone else reading this and being confused.

I got it running using Amazon's **Route53** service, doing the following.

```
Nameservers       NS       Route53
domain.com        A        IP Address of Server Box
www.domain.com    CNAME    domain.com
```

Then in my domain registrar (**NetworkSolutions.com**) I set the Nameservers to the ones given to me by **Route53**
And then in the **Plesk** server, I just did not have any kind of DNS setup (I told it to turn DNS resolution off)

Waiting a few hours to let all the propagation magic happen, it seemed to magically work! (Hurrah!)